# Maxscale not allowed to connect mysql8 with java application

Tags: mysql, jdbc, maxscale

I have a **mysql 8.0.3** database over top of that **maxscale server** is running when i tried to connect with that mysql jdbc driver this error is coming **unknown system variable 'query_cache_size'**. But when i tried to connect directly to database is working for me. query_cache_size parameters removed from mysql 8.

Comment: Also you can try with dbeaver (Java based client) to connect with database.

Comment: The query cache has been deprecated. BTW 8.0.3 is a very old version (4 years) and was pre-general availability (a release candidate) so please do not use it for production.

Comment: With your 8.0.3 database, REMOVE from your my.cnf or my.ini and Global Variable that starts with query_cache because the function is REMOVED or will be REMOVED in future versions of MySQL instances.  MariaDB does still support query_cache at this time so this suggestion to REMOVE query_cache anything DOES NOT apply to any MaridDB instance at this time.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** With MXS-2890 fixed, you should now be able to configure `version_string=8.0.16-mysql` in MaxScale to solve this problem

---

This is most likely caused by the following bug: https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MXS-2890

The MariaDB JDBC connector should not suffer from this problem which means installing it instead of the MySQL JDBC connector can be used as a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

In your /etc/maxscale.cnf you can add version_string=5.6

````
[Read-Write-Service]
type=service
router=readwritesplit
servers=master
version_string=5.6
user=user
password=********```

after that i am  able to access mysql8 on top of maxscale server.
````